# windows universal app development cognitive services

Tags: uwp, azure-cognitive-services

```
private async void getemotion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        emotionresult = await emotionServiceClient.RecognizeAsync(imageStream.AsStream());

        if(emotionresult !=null)
        {
            Scores score = emotionresult[0].Scores;
            Output.Text = "Your emoptions are:\n" +
                "Happiness: " + score.Happiness + "\n" +
                "Sadness: " + score.Sadness + "\n" +
                "Suprise: " + score.Surprise + "\n" +
                "Fear: " + score.Fear + "\n" +
                "Anger:" + score.Anger + "\n" +
                "Contempt: " + score.Contempt + "\n" +
                "Disgust: " + score.Disgust + "\n" +
                "Neutral: " + score.Neutral + "\n";
        }
    }
```

This is the code which i implemented on a button click after capturing an image to get emotional score but getting error in the code in the line
below

```
Scores score = emotionresult[0].Scores;
```

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.Contract.EmotionScores' to 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Emotion.Contract.Scores'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    App1    C:\Users\Akshay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\MainPage.xaml.cs    93  Active

Answer (score 3):

The simplest fix is to change the explicit `Scores` type to be `var`, and let the compiler figure out the type for you.

Some of the core types were moved into a common assembly in the last update, and it looks like a cast was missed in the back-compat types which is causing this issue. It'll be added in the next update to re-enable the explicit Scores type again.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    var emotionResult = await emotionServiceClient.RecognizeAsync(imageStream.AsStream());
    var score = emotionResult[0].Scores;                 
    if (emotionResult != null)
    {
        ...
```